# Create an Actionbar OptionsMenu in an PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, preferencefragment

I run into a problem while I was settings up the Preferences for my `App`.

I would like to have a Button in the `ActionBar` (e.g. Save) but my `ActionBar` is not showing anything. I put this Line in the `onCreate` Method:

`this.setHasOptionsMenu(true)`;

And implemented the

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

methods as well. However, it does not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your button item in your action menu layout something like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    your_icon:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
   />
```

Comment: your_icon:  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:your_icon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

Comment: Oh god i forgot showAsAction, this is embarrassing. Anyway thanks for help :)