# No action on clicking icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-menu

I am using code from from Android Developer to display the ActionBar but I cannot get it to work. If I click 
on the *icon* on the ActionBar there is no response, but clicking the text BACK (in this case) works; however on 
removing the icon line from the xml file (below) everything works fine!
So how can I correct this? This is the res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
      android:title="@string/action_help"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_back"
      android:title="@string/action_back"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Removing the "icon=" line fixes things, but I want the icons displayed. The MainActivity (which only responds 
to action_back clicked) and strings.xml files are shown below:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
        case R.id.action_help :
            Toast.makeText(this, "Help clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_back :
            Toast.makeText(this, "Back clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }

 <resources>
     <string name="action_help">Help</string>
     <string name="action_back">Back</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Your `menu` has problem missing ´xmlns´, check this post [Create an Actionbar OptionsMenu in an PreferenceFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754483/create-an-actionbar-optionsmenu-in-an-preferencefragment/23756042#23756042)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use this code instead of yours and check whether its working or not.
Hope it works.   

 @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id){
            case R.id.action_help :
                Toast.makeText(this, "Help clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
            case R.id.action_back :
                Toast.makeText(this, "Back clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               break;


        }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

Comment: Worked fine and thank you very much. I have a few more ActionBar questions but will ask in a new post.

Comment: My pleasure..n sure...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to include both this in your menu.xml file

appcompat v7
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  

appcompat v7+
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: When I put the above in I just get a bunch of wavy red lines! I am relatively new at this so how do I determine whether I have appcompat v7 or 7+ whatever that may be?

Comment: Appcompat v7 is for below api level 14. Check your manifest files minsdkVersion and maxsdkVersion.

Comment: I tried xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", the compiler said unused token or whatever, but then produced a bunch of "Cannot Resolve Symbol R". "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  just gave a bunch of wavy red lines which I could net clear.

Comment: first tell me which api level you are working on..above 7 or below 7.?

Comment: Gradle: compiledSdkV 16, minsdkV 16, targetSdkV 21; and I can get a click respose _once_ on the _icon_ if I reload Android Studio.